# Why we applied pipe and filter instead of layered architecture in compiler?

Tags: filter, pipe, layer

Why we applied pipe and filter instead of layered architecture in compiler?

Comment: Who is we? What compiler?

Comment: Yeah i mean to say why compiler is using pipe and filter architecture instead of layered architecture?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: As Pipe & Filter style is an Architectural pattern for stream processing. It consists of any number of components (filters) that transform or filter data, before passing it on via connectors (pipes) to other components.  Compilers are the typical application for the pipe and filter style. and layer is also another architecture pattern. so my question is why compilers are using pipe and filter architecture instead of layered architecture. because compiler architecture is looking more similar to layered architecture not pipe and filters.